# socket with nginx cliented ,but can't send or listen

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

Client request the socket url is http://127.0.0.1:81/chat. the socket server url is http://127.0.0.1:19968/ ,so I use nginx to rewrite, though I request http://127.0.0.1:81/chat return http status code is 101, but the socket listen envent is not work and can't send message

I'v searched from nignx site, but not found anything.

if I remove location 1 config ,then request http://127.0.0.1:81/chat resopnse 
 404,why?

this is my nignx config:

```
upstream socket_nodes {
        ip_hash;
        #server srv1.app.com:5000 weight=5;
        #server srv2.app.com:5000;
        #server srv3.app.com:5000;
        server 127.0.0.1:19968;
    }


    server {
        listen       81;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
        root   "C:/Users/najin/Desktop/docker/docker/html/";
        #root   "D:/phpStudy/PHPTutorial/WWW/PhalApi/";

        //location 1
        location / {
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;

          index  index.html index.htm index.php l.php;
          autoindex  on;
        }

        //location 2
        location /chat {
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://socket_nodes;
          #if (!-e $request_filename) {
          #      rewrite  ^/ / break;
          #}
          rewrite  ^/chat / last;
          index  index.html index.htm index.php l.php;
          autoindex  on;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
```

when I request http://127.0.0.1:81/chat , response :

Request URL: ws://localhost:81/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket

Request Method: GET

Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols

but client socket listent not work and can't send message.when I send nothing happen.

Thank U.